# How I can add multiple rows in database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have application mvc4 c# and I need add 
Multiple record to database  but wen I use db.savechanges()  in foreach  I get error 
And   Wen use it outside of loop it can save last recode only

Comment: db.SaveChanges() commits all your changes to the database. You should use it outside the loop. Put some code, so we can check why it is saving only the last record

Answer (score 0):

did you try a thing like AddRange?

instead of `foreach` try to do `AddRange(toAddCollection)` and then `SaveChanges()`